# Como pegar os valores dentro de múltiplas tags

Tags: php, html

Olá,

Tenho a seguinte página em HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text">Valor 1</div>
    <div id="text">Valor 2</div>
    <div id="text">Valor 3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou usando a seguinte função em PHP para pegar o texto entre uma tag:

```
function capturar($string, $start, $end) {
    $str = explode($start, $string);
    $str = explode($end, $str[1]);
    return $str[0];
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents('http://localhost/exemplo.html');
$valor = capturar($url, '<div id="text">', '</div>');
echo $valor;
```

Porem, quando tem mais de uma tag idêntica com o texto entre elas diferente, ela só pega o texto entre a primeira tag, oque eu faria para para pegar todos textos entre essa tag (`<div id="text">`, `</div>`) e adicionar eles entre uma array?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Olha `id` é um identificador único, não podem se repetir na mesma página

Answer (score -1):

O ideal é usar o preg_match_all.

```
function capturar($string, $start, $end) {

    $start = str_replace('/', '\/', $start);
    $end = str_replace('/', '\/', $end);
    preg_match_all('/'.$start.'(.*?)'.$end.'/', $string, $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1]))
        return $matches[1];
    else return false;
}
```

Pode não estar perfeito, pois poderá ser preciso fazer "escape" a outros caracteres. Agora só faz ao /

Answer (score -1):

Existem várias formas de buscar elementos em um documento HTML.
Primeiro você deve notar que o seu HTML está inválido, pois o atributo `id` deve ser único em todo o documento.

Você pode utilizar consultas [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) para resolver o seu problema:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text">Valor 1</div>
    <div id="text">Valor 2</div>
    <div id="text">Valor 3</div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$crawler = new DomDocument();
$crawler->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($crawler);

$elementos = $xpath->query("//div[@id='text']");

echo '<pre>';
foreach($elementos as $objeto) {
    var_dump($objeto->nodeValue);
}
```

Uma outra forma um pouco mais fácil e que lhe propricia mais recursos é através de bibliotecas de terceiros. Uma biblioteca bem poderosa e útil a [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

Para instalar usando composer:

```
composer require symfony/dom-crawler
```

A mesma solução de antes, utilizando `DomCrawler`:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text">Valor 1</div>
    <div id="text">Valor 2</div>
    <div id="text">Valor 3</div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$elementos = $crawler->filterXPath("//div[@id='text']")->extract(['_text']);

echo '<pre>';
foreach($elementos as $elemento) {
   var_dump($elemento);
}
```

Note que alem deste exemplo, a [documentação](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) oficial ainda indica que é possível utilizar seletores CSS, incluindo a dependência `symfony/css-selector`.